# How to sync data of multiple Azure Web Site instances

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure website running on several instances on Basic compute mode. I want to synchronize local data (just a few small numbers like number of online users, total app users, not whole tables or files) between the instances. How can I achieve this? I've seen [Refreshing Data on all Azure Instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398627/refreshing-data-on-all-azure-instances) but it didn't help much. My current naive approach is writing these values to my database, and in my application code, keeping local changes, and syncing the actual data from the database every few minutes, which is OK for my application. But I'm looking for a more elegant way to achieving sync between instances. Is this possible? If yes, how?

Comment: Maybe you can *only* use the database? At the moment you have a stateful web app which not best-practice for various reasons.

Comment: @usr it's not a best-practice for many things, but it's useful for my purpose. The stateful data is only displayed to the moderators of a mobile application's server at a webpage, and I'm pushing changes to the moderators with SignalR, which is enough for my purpose. I'm wondering if there are any Azure APIs that can handle sync between instances.

Answer (score 3):

There is not an API that will support syncing state between instances.  However, here are a few ideas you might consider.

**Local File System**

The web site instances share a common file system.  So, you could just write data to a .txt file in your App_Data folder and all the instances will use that same file.  This would at least eliminate the dependency on a database for such simple data.

**Caching**

Another option is to write the data to a cache.  Your options for this would be to use the Managed Cache service or the new Redis Cache (in preview).

**Storage Tables**

This may not be any better than your current solution.  But, it is cheap and very efficient.

Comment: With Multiple Instances is it Thread Safe?